# Plotting with two variable

Tags: plotting

```
GF = 1.16*10^(-5)
MW = 80
mt = 172.44
x = (mt^2)/(MW^2)
C1 = (x/8)*((x - 6)/(x - 1) + ((3*x + 2)/(x - 1)^2)*Log[10, x])
S1 = ((4*x - 11*x^2 + x^3)/(4*(1 - x)^2)) - (3/2)*(((Log[10, x])*x^3)/(1 - x)^3)
λ = 0.0396
a = (C1/S1)*4
b = (2*Sqrt[2]*3.14^2)/(GF*MW^2*S1)
M = ((1 + (a*U*Cos[Φ])/λ + (b*U^2*
      Cos[2 Φ])/λ^2)^2 + ((a*U*
      Sin[Φ])/λ + (b*U^2*
      Sin[2 Φ])/λ^2)^2)/0.8464
```

If I want to plot `U` vs. `Φ` then what command I will use?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I will try to plot an implicit function without using `ContourPlot`.

First define a `SetDelay`,

```
M[U_, \[CapitalPhi]_] := ((1 + (a*U*
          Cos[\[CapitalPhi]])/\[Lambda] + (b*U^2*
          Cos[2 \[CapitalPhi]])/\[Lambda]^2)^2 + ((a*U*
          Sin[\[CapitalPhi]])/\[Lambda] + (b*U^2*
          Sin[2 \[CapitalPhi]])/\[Lambda]^2)^2)/0.8464
```

then make a list of data points using `Table`. While doing this, solve for the dependent variable `U`,

```
data = Table[{\[CapitalPhi], U /. Solve[M[U, \[CapitalPhi]] == 0, U][[1]]}, {\[CapitalPhi], -5,
     5, 0.1}];
```

From the list you will see that we getting complex numbers, so lets plot both,

```
ListLinePlot[{Re@data, Im@data}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image]

There are multiple roots, you can choose it by changing the placement position `[[1]]`.

Second root,

[image]

Third root,

[image]

Fourth root,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really established a relationship between `U` and `Φ` for plotting, but if we change your last statement to an equation instead of an assignment, we can solve for `U` in terms of `Φ` and then make plots over a range of `M`.

```
M =.;
GF = 1.16*10^(-5);
MW = 80;
mt = 172.44;
x = (mt^2)/(MW^2);
C1 = (x/8)*((x - 6)/(x - 1) + ((3*x + 2)/(x - 1)^2)*Log[10, x]);
S1 = ((4*x - 11*x^2 + x^3)/(4*(1 - x)^2)) - (3/
      2)*(((Log[10, x])*x^3)/(1 - x)^3);
λ = 0.0396;
a = (C1/S1)*4;
b = (2*Sqrt[2]*3.14^2)/(GF*MW^2*S1);
ueq = M == ((1 + (a*U*Cos[Φ])/λ + (b*U^2*
          Cos[2 Φ])/λ^2)^2 + ((a*U*
          Sin[Φ])/λ + (b*U^2*
          Sin[2 Φ])/λ^2)^2)/0.8464
```

Then solve for `U` by the last equation

```
Sol = Solve[ueq, U] // Simplify;
```

We get four very long solutions and each solution has quadrants of `Φ` that have real values yielding curves and quadrants that have complex values which yield no curve.  The more interesting plots are those where all four solutions are plotted on the same plot.  We will just make a Table of plots over a range of `M`.

Assign the four results for `U`.

```
U1[M_, Φ_] = U /. Sol[[1]];
U2[M_, Φ_] = U /. Sol[[2]];
U3[M_, Φ_] = U /. Sol[[3]];
U4[M_, Φ_] = U /. Sol[[4]];

gifs = Table[ Plot[{U1[M, Φ], U2[M, Φ], U3[M, Φ], U4[M, Φ]} // 
     Chop, {Φ, 0, 2 π}, PlotRange -> {-.0016, .0016}, 
    PlotLabel -> "M = " <> ToString[M]], {M, .5, 5, .25}];
ListAnimate[gifs]
```

[image]

Note that these plots are for the real values of `U` only.

Comment: If I want to vary this M value within the range then what command I will use? Means  if I want to plot sol[1], Sol[2], Sol[3] and sol[4] together in a single plotting then what command I will use?

Comment: Actually I want to plot U Vs Phi by varying M from 0.6 to 1.24 in the same graph. What command I will use?

Comment: Change the range of M in the Table command to `{M, 0.6, 1.24, 0.1}` or whatever interval you prefer.

Comment: Can I write these commands directly in mathematica or is it necessary to change somethings?

Comment: These answers are Mathematica code.  Just copy and paste into a notebook and change (or not) whatever you want and execute.

Comment: It is helpful for me. But I want to plot not an animated picture. Then what command I will use?

Comment: Assign a value to `M` and plot it without the `Table`.

Comment: Can you write a command to plot without table please?